# Rails 3 show/hide dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to change my app so that when a user registers, if they select a certain region they are from (eg. Europe) it shows another select box with a list of countries, or hides it if not Europe.

I've found quite a lot of good tutorials to do this on Rails2 but none of them seem to work on Rails 3.

Anyone know of a good way to do this nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [idea of Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) still holds in Rails 3. I suggest you start using that idea of dynamic select menus customizing it for your specific needs and come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a go with that but when I tried to run the javascripts/dynamic_states.js.erb in a browser it just showed the pure javascript and didn't run the ruby code, any ideas?

Comment: When I view the URL http://localhost:3000/javascripts/dynamic_states.js.erb  having put the code in as per this tutorial the raw ruby code appears, rails doesn't seem to run that file as an erb.  When I run it without the .erb I get a page not found error.

Comment: I have now fixed this by adding a route,   match '/javascripts/dynamic_states' => 'javascripts#dynamic_states'

Comment: Are all you problems with this solved? does it work now? If not update the question with the approach you're following and new problem with that.